# How to Calculate vertical distance traveled by Android Phone when falling from hand?

Tags: android, height, accelerometer, android-sensors

So I have used the accelerometer for checking if the phone is falling. This part is working great.
 
I used the below-given link for the above purpose.
https://github.com/altermarkive/experimental-fall-detector-android-app

Now the next step was to calculate the distance it traveled vertically. 
I have tried so many things for this purpose but every time the height is coming incorrect. 
Also, the height varies on different devices differently.

I am getting the acceleration data from the Accelerometer sensor, after which I have used the below-given formulas for calculating the distance traveled.

The 1st code I tried : -

```
    long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        // sampling frequency f= 10Hz.
        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > CHECK_INTERVAL) {

            long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
            lastUpdate = curTime;

            accel_values = event.values.clone();

            if (last_accel_values != null) {

                mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
                mAccelCurrent =(float)Math.sqrt(accel_values[0]* accel_values[0] + 
                          accel_values[1]*accel_values[1]
                        + accel_values[2]*accel_values[2]);

                Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_CHANGED);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putFloat(Constants.VALUE, mAccelCurrent);
                msg.setData(bundle);
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

                mWindow.add(mAccelCurrent);
                if (mWindow.isFull() && mWindow.isFallDetected()){
                    Log.w(TAG, "Fall detected by window class");
                    actime = curTime - diffTime;
                    velocity = actime * acceleration;
                    avgvelocity = velocity / 2;
                    height = avgvelocity * actime;
                    mWindow.clear();
                    msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_EMERGENCY);
                    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
            }

            last_accel_values = accel_values.clone();
        }
    }
```

The 2nd code I tried : -

```
            final double alpha = 0.8;

            double gravity[] = new double[3], linear_acceleration[] = new double[3];
            // Isolate the force of gravity with the low-pass filter.
            gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * sensorEvent.values[0];
            gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * sensorEvent.values[1];
            gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * sensorEvent.values[2];
            double curr_gravity = gravity[0] + gravity[1] + gravity[2];

            // Remove the gravity contribution with the high-pass filter.
            linear_acceleration[0] = sensorEvent.values[0] - gravity[0];
            linear_acceleration[1] = sensorEvent.values[1] - gravity[1];
            linear_acceleration[2] = sensorEvent.values[2] - gravity[2];

            double curr_acc = linear_acceleration[0] + linear_acceleration[1] + linear_acceleration[2];

            long seconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
            double velocity = curr_acc * seconds;
            double init_vel = velocity / 2;

            double time = (velocity - init_vel) / curr_gravity;
            double height = (((seconds * 9.8)/2) - init_vel);
```

The 3rd formula I tried:-

long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

```
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        // sampling frequency f= 10Hz.
        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > CHECK_INTERVAL) {

            long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
            lastUpdate = curTime;

            accel_values = event.values.clone();

            if (last_accel_values != null) {

                mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
                mAccelCurrent =(float)Math.sqrt(accel_values[0]* accel_values[0] + 
                          accel_values[1]*accel_values[1]
                        + accel_values[2]*accel_values[2]);

                Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_CHANGED);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putFloat(Constants.VALUE, mAccelCurrent);
                msg.setData(bundle);
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

                mWindow.add(mAccelCurrent);
                if (mWindow.isFull() && mWindow.isFallDetected()){
                    Log.w(TAG, "Fall detected by window class");
                    actime = curTime - diffTime;
                    height = 0.5*9.8*actime*actime;
                    mWindow.clear();
                    msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_EMERGENCY);
                    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
            }

            last_accel_values = accel_values.clone();
        }
    }
```

The fourth formula and the current code in use:-

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        // sampling frequency f= 10Hz.
        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > CHECK_INTERVAL) {

            lastUpdate = curTime;

            accel_values = event.values.clone();

            if (last_accel_values != null) {

                mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;

                final double alpha = 0.8;

                double gravity[] = new double[3], linear_acceleration[] = new double[3];
                gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
                gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
                gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

                linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
                linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
                linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];

                double mAccelCurrent = linear_acceleration[0] + linear_acceleration[1] + linear_acceleration[2];

                double loX = event.values[0];
                double loY = event.values[1];
                double loZ = event.values[2];

                double loAccelerationReader = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(loX, 2)
                        + Math.pow(loY, 2)
                        + Math.pow(loZ, 2));

                DecimalFormat precision = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                double ldAccRound = Double.parseDouble(precision.format(loAccelerationReader));

                // Send the value back to the Activity
                Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_CHANGED);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putFloat(Constants.VALUE, (float) mAccelCurrent);
                msg.setData(bundle);
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

                mWindow.add((float) mAccelCurrent);
                if (mWindow.isFull() && mWindow.isFallDetected() && ldAccRound > 12d) {
                    long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    Log.e(TAG, "Fall detected by window class");

                    long time = stop - curTime;

                    double currtime1 = (double) time / 1000;

                    velocity = currtime1 * mAccelCurrent;
                    height = velocity * currtime1 * currtime1;
                    Log.e("Height", "Vel : " + velocity + ", Avg : " + avgvelocity + ", Height : " +
                            height);

                    mWindow.clear();
                    if (height > 0) {
                        AppPreferences.setFall(context, String.valueOf(height));
                        /*mAccelCurrent = 0;
                        velocity = 0;
                        avgvelocity = 0;
                        height = 0;*/

                        msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_EMERGENCY);
                        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Height not calculated properly. Please drop again",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            last_accel_values = accel_values.clone();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried using other sensors for the same purpose like Barometer but I'm getting the same result from them (height is not coming as expected). 
Also, I tried looking for third party SDKs but they are also using their own hardware.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Also if anyone could guide in the proper way, that would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have the same mistake in all three approaches. In all three, at some point you multiply your acceleration with an absolute timestamp from `System.currentTimeMillis()`. This is milliseconds since 1970 and has no direct meaning in your situation unless you use it to calculate time intervals as differences. In some examples you do that, but you subtract it again from `System.currentTimeMillis()` which again results in milliseconds since 1970.

It looks like you try to implement s = 1/2 a t², but this is only valid for a constant acceleration from rest over a time interval t. If you want to derive the distance from a sequence of measure accelerations, you need to numerically integrate them (this sounds harder than it is) and probably want to employ some filtering.

However, my recommendation is to simply assume a free fall with an acceleration of 9.81 m/s². This neglects air drag or local variations in Earth's acceleration, but unless you want to use this in some weird situations, this is probably much more precise than using the readings from the sensor. Espacially when the phone rotates, but also due to bad calibration and some filtering to split actual acceleration from gravitational acceleration, I would not expect the sensor readings to be superior to approximating a perfect free fall. After all, smartphones are rather dense objects and not to much influenced by air drag.

The upside is that you can simply use s = 1/2 a t². Just make sure that t is not a time interval since 1970, but the timer interval from the beginning of the fall (which you said you can detect reliably) until the end of the fall (i.e. the difference of the time stamp at the beginning and the time stamp at the end). Also, I would suggest to use the time from the sensor events instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()` as it has a better resolution and is designed for this type of calculations.

Comment: Hi, at the moment I'm using the formula h = at² for calculating the height. Also, the t which I use is the time difference between the beginning and end of the drop. 
But this is not giving accurate height. Every time there is a difference of 0.5 to 1 feet. Also, this difference varies on different devices. Is there any way I can make it more accurate?

Comment: It's 1/2 a t², but I assume that this is a typo, since it's correct in your code. However in your code example 1 and 2, you are not using the time difference between the beginning and the end of the drop. You use
`actime = curTime - diffTime`
since you set 
`long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);`
your actime simply equals `lastUpdate` which is `currentTimeMillis()`.

If you fixed this, please show your current code that results in the bad results and maybe explain a bit more about the your actual experimental setup.

Comment: Hi, I have added the final and current code used by me above as the fourth formula. In that, I'm able to get the beginning time of the drop, and stop time is taken at the moment when the fall is detected. At the moment, I have no way to detect if the phone has stopped dropping. I get a time difference using time-diff = stop-time - start-time. Then I get velocity = acceleration*timediff. Then I calculate height = velocity*timediff*timediff. But sometimes the time-diff comes as zero which makes the whole calculations as 0 and when it's not zero, it randomly gives correct/incorrect height.

Comment: There are a few things I spotted in your code:
* It is h = 1/2 a t². You are calculating h = a t³.
* You are resetting gravity[] to zero each time.
* Your linear_acceleration[0,1,2] is just 0.8*event.values[0,1,2]
* You simply add up x+y+z for total acceleration. (Few lines later you do it properly.)
* You are using TYPE_ACCELEROMETER to get the acceleration. But this sensor does not do what you think it does. For a perfectly free fall it will yield zero acceleration!
* According to your comment in the fifth line, you limit the check rate to 10 Hz, limiting your temporal resolution.

Comment: Your code contains much stuff that is not related to the question. I only commented on relevant lines and had to heavily cut down my answer due to the character limit.
So, please, try to start with a minimal version. Do not try to get the acceleration from the sensors, do not try to send intermediate results to your activity and do not try to handle vector acceleration. Simply use the sensor do determine start and stop of the drop and calculate 9.81/2×t². Show minimal code and give results along with tested drop height. From there we can add features and optimizations (if even necessary).

Comment: Hi, I'll definitely try your solution but is there any way to know when the phone stops falling. I've been trying to look for the same but I'm not getting any proper solutions.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution. Created a demo for the same. The problem I'm facing in this is that I'm unable to detect when the phone has stopped falling. At the moment, I'm reading the accelerometer readings in order to detect when the phone is not moving. But I'm getting different readings on different heights. For example, if my phone is placed on the table first it gives 16 accelerometer readings. Now if I move it up and then place it on the table it's giving me 20 accelerometer readings. Any idea how to fix this or how to detect when fall is stopped.

Comment: Just look at the total acceleration in the TYPE_ACCELEROMETER event. As this is not physical acceleration but the force acting on a sample mass, it includes Earth's acceleration which is cancelled in the phone's frame of reference if it is falling. In other words: The total from TYPE_ACCELEROMETER is close to zero while the phone is droping. Define a threshold: The first reading below the threshold is your start and the next one exceeding the threshold is your stop.

I do not really understand your question about 16/20 readings. What rate and reporting mode did you request from the sensor?

Comment: I'm using SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST reporting mode in the accelerometer. Should I use some other one? Please let me know.

Comment: No, that should be ideal for the approach I described.

Comment: So, I've been trying the free fall formula but it not giving me good results. Also, the time difference which I'm getting for the drops is very low said if I drop my phone from height of 3 feet then the time difference I get is 0.01. Now if I put this time in free fall formula, it gives incorrect height. Also sometimes, I get time difference as 0 which gives me height as zero. I also tried 1/2at² formula and it's giving me better results on my device. But still not accurate enough. Can you provide me any code example for this?